# Reduce to canonical form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Help solve the equation of mathematical physics, reduce the equation to canonical form

$$y^{2} u_{x x}+x^{2} u_{y y}=0$$

Comment: You don't provide the domain and boundary condition.